# Generating a list from complex dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, python

I have a dictionary `dict1['a'] = [ [1,2], [3,4] ]` and need to generate a list out of it as `l1 = [2, 4]`. That is, a list out of the second element of each inner list. It can be a separate list or even the dictionary can be modified as `dict1['a'] = [2,4]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each value in the dictionary is a list of pairs, then this should do it for you:

```
[pair[1] for pairlist in dict1.values() for pair in pairlist]
```

As you can see:

- `dict1.values()` gets you just the values in your dict,
- `for pairlist in dict1.values()` gets you all the lists of pairs,
- `for pair in pairlist` gets you all the pairs in each of those lists,
- and `pair[1]` gets you the second value in each pair.

Try it out. The Python shell is your friend!...

```
>>> dict1 = {}
>>> dict1['a'] = [[1,2], [3,4]]
>>> dict1['b'] = [[5, 6], [42, 69], [220, 284]]
>>> 
>>> dict1.values()
[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [42, 69], [220, 284]]]
>>> 
>>> [pairlist for pairlist in dict1.values()]
[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [42, 69], [220, 284]]]
>>> # No real difference here, but we can refer to each list now.
>>> 
>>> [pair for pairlist in dict1.values() for pair in pairlist]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [42, 69], [220, 284]]
>>> 
>>> # Finally...
>>> [pair[1] for pairlist in dict1.values() for pair in pairlist]
[2, 4, 6, 69, 284]
```

While I'm at it, I'll just say: [ipython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) loves you!

Answer (score 8):

Given a list:

```
>>> lst = [ [1,2], [3,4] ]
```

You can extract the second element of each sublist with a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> [x[1] for x in lst]
[2, 4]
```

If you want to do this for every value in a dictionary, you can iterate over the dictionary.  I'm not sure exactly what you want your final data to look like, but something like this may help:

```
>>> dict1 = {}
>>> dict1['a'] = [ [1,2], [3,4] ]
>>> [(k, [x[1] for x in v]) for k, v in dict1.items()]   
[('a', [2, 4])]
```

`dict.items()` returns (key, value) pairs from the dictionary, as a list.  So this code will extract each key in your dictionary and pair it with a list generated as above.

Comment: And in Python 3, could do this in a dict comprehension, too, if a dictionary result should be preferred - looks like:  {k: [x[1] for x in v] for k,v in dict1.items()}

Answer (score 0):

> a list out of the second element of
>   each inner list

that sounds like `[sl[1] for sl in dict1['a']]` -- so what's the QUESTION?!-)